# Add margin to JTable column (Mac)

Tags: java, macos, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a `JTable` looking like this:

[image]

Is it possible to add a margin for the column text?

I have tried to add a `TableCellRenderer` and add an `EmptyBorder`. **Problem**: the background color gets white like this:

[image]

Any idea how to add margin and keep the default background color?

```
public class JTableColumnMargin extends JFrame {

    public JTableColumnMargin() {
        Object rowData[][] = { { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "Row1-Column3" }, { "Row2-Column1", "Row2-Column2", "Row2-Column3" } };
        Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three" };
        JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);

        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            table.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setHeaderRenderer(new HeaderRenderer(table));
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setSize(500, 150);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class HeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
        private DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer;

        private HeaderRenderer(JTable table) {
            renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
            Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
            JLabel label = (JLabel) c;
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 10));
            return label;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JTableColumnMargin();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegating to the original renderer basically is the right direction to go, just slightly differently:

- use a compoundBorder of the original and the emptyBorder
- nudge the original renderer to re-set the border to its original by making the padded border a UIResource

Something like:

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
        Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column) {
    JComponent comp = (JComponent) originalRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, 
            isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    Border originalBorder = comp.getBorder();
    comp.setBorder(new CompoundBorderUIResource(originalBorder, 
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 0)));
    return comp;
}
```

It's brittle, though, as LAFs might ignore your setting: the trick works fine for WinLAF, but not at all for Nimbus - so don't know the outcome on Mac.

Comment: Looking got dame perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use next header Renderer:

```
private static class HeaderRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {

    private HeaderRenderer() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"),BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 10)));
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        setText(value.toString());
        return this;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to add a margin to the text and not center the column text. And it also seems like setting the border to UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder") changes the custom background to a new background...

Comment: I've changed my code. `UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder")` return default decorations for `JTableHeader` cell.

Comment: By looking at the code it looks nice. But I´m not quite happy with the result. The default table(at the bottom) feels more smooth: http://i.imgur.com/QLNxCpN.png